Precalculate Rigidbody movement in Unity
Is there a way to precalculate movement from a Rigidbody in Unity and show this with a line renderer for example? I want to make a physics based marble game and show the path the marble is going to take with a line renderer or something like that. The problem is, though, that I only know ways that woukd draw a line with the speed the marble would roll down, such as having another invisible marble. Setting Time.TimeScale is also no solution because the constant change of timespeed is no good.

Have you read Multi-scene physics or Multiple worlds - simulating groups of bodies separately from the Unity docs?

The TrajectoryPredictor asset on the unity asset store is a good tool for things like this.
